# How to set year limit in DatePickerDialog in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have been researching on putting limits in `DatePickerDialog`, but nothing seems to work, I don't really know what is wrong and how to make it work here is my current code:

```
    public void getdate() {
        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }

        };
        birthdate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    new DatePickerDialog(Register.this, date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private void updateLabel() {

        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; // In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        birthdate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Comment: the datepicker has `setMaxDate` and  `setMinDate` which you can use to manipulate accordingly. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html. use `getDatePicker()` on dialog